# Accessing feature class from file geodatabase for intersect in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I want to intersect one polygon file in a file geodatabase with multiple point files in a folder.

To access the file in the file geodtabase I do this:

```
arcpy.env.workspace=r'F:\Sheyenne\Sheyenne_lidar\for_histos\lidar.gdb'
shapes=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
```

when I do this:

```
for shape in shapes:
    print shape
```

my file is returned, named `lidar_final_poly`.

To access the files in the folder I want to intersect with I do this:

```
arcpy.env.workspace=r'C:\path_to_intersects'
intersects=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(*.shp)
```

and then to intersect I do this:

```
for i in intersects:
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([shapes,i]), outpath)
```

but this returns:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset F:\Sheyenne\Pixel_Regression\Viking\GDD_regress\NDII\shapefiles\NDII_ts.shp #;lidar_final_poly # does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Intersect).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths to your files are changing when `arcpy.env.workspace` is changed, so when the script is run it can't find some of the files.  e.g. `print shape` returns `lidar_final_poly` but it needs to return `F:\Sheyenne\Sheyenne_lidar\for_histos\lidar.gdb\lidar_final_poly`

```
import arcpy, os

gdbPath = r'F:\Sheyenne\Sheyenne_lidar\for_histos\lidar.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = gdbPath
shapes = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

shapeList = list()
for shape in shapes:
    print shape
    shapeList.append(os.path.join(gdbPath, shape)

shapePath = r'C:\path_to_intersects'
arcpy.env.workspace = shapePath
intersects = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(*.shp)

for i in intersects:
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([shapeList, i]), outpath)
```